# How could i get Class<? extends List<AlarmRule>> instatnce?

Tags: java, android

I need to get Class< ? extends List < AlarmRule > > instance.

This is my code:

```
  public static BoundedMatcher<Object, List<AlarmRule>> setBind() {
        Class<? extends List<AlarmRule>> clazz = null; // I need to give clazz a value,but i don't know how.
        return new BoundedMatcher<Object, List<AlarmRule>>(clazz) {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with item content: ");
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(List<AlarmRule> list) {
             return    list.stream().anyMatch(alarmRule -> test_reminder_corn.equals(alarmRule.cron));
            }
        };
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you be more specific please

Comment: no class can extend List since List is an abstract class

Comment: @AJay ok , I have edit it . Can you understand this ?

Comment: @Roy But an Interface can extend List

Comment: @Roy I have edit it , Do you have ideas for this ?

Comment: Class<? extends List<AlarmRule>> clazz = (Class<? extends List<AlarmRule>>) ArrayList.class;

Have you tried this ?

Comment: @AJay I  try your answer just now. but it seems not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write like this

```
public static BoundedMatcher<Object, List> setBind() {
    return new BoundedMatcher<Object, List>(List.class) {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with item content: ");
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(List list) {
            // convert every object in list to AlarmRule
            return  false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to pass `List.class` in the constructor.

However, because of java type erasure, any `List` may be passed to your matcher so you need to add additional code to ensure your list actually contains `AlarmRule` objects or you will get a `ClassCastException` at runtime.